# Thymeleaf loading templates from database on fly

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

Iam new to thymeleaf and I am trying to send an email with a predefined template using spring mail and spring thymeleaf. I could able to send an email with a template in my templates folder, but i need to have a table which has different templates, and I need to read those template at runtime using template name, and utilize those template for sending email. I could not able to find a complete example which follows java based annotations in spring boot. can anyone share an example code with the explanation for the same?

Comment: Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28993936/how-to-use-springtemplateengine-when-using-spring-boot).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I need templates from the database. I am following, this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43598674/how-to-read-a-thymeleaf-template-from-db-in-thymeleaf-3-0-5). but itsnot full fledged, like how can i use that template